RFID 522 reader with RPi4 only reads sometimes
I have an RFID 522 reader connected with Raspberry Pi 4 and it only works sometimes. I followed the schematic from a tutorial and used the corresponding code. The reader works perfectly fine, detecing the card and activating some servos, but then just stops for no reason.
I haven't moved any components or wires and the code was constantly running and the reader just stopped working. Sometimes the reader works perfectly fine, even after moving the components and stopping and running the code but then it suddenly no longer works.
I have tried disableing and reenableing SPI in RPi settings and that worked once or twice. Resetting Raspberry also worked a few times, but I need a permanent solution. I have tried looking for simmilar issues online and couldn't find any ways to deal with it.
I saw somebody mention that 3.3v isn't enough since 3.5v is considered a high signal and only that gets read, but 5v could damage the reader so I should use voltage level shifter or divider circuit. Since I can't get level shifter right now I tried making divider circuit, first with 10k ohm and 3.3k ohm resistors and later with 1k ohm and 330 ohm resistors but that hasn't worked.
Is it possible that the reader is not working correctly and needs to be replaced? I don't have any store that sells the readers anywhere close so unless I'm sure the reader needs replacing I don't want to risk ordering another one.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

if you have problem with hardware then you are in wrong place.

maybe ask on similar portal for Raspberry Pi or on official forum Raspberry Pi

I have tried asking on Reddit and on Raspberry Pi forum already. I got one answer suggesting I use gpio.cleanup when ending the program but that hasn't helped.
